# TeXmaker doesn't show subfigure's reference number

Tags: floats, cross-referencing, ref

I am running a main.tex file in which I use the \input{} command for my subfiles: subfile1.tex, ...
Now, I have some figures in my subfiles, say subfile1.tex, and I want to insert a reference to that figure (both in the subfile1.tex itself and in the main.tex) using a \ref{fig:my_figure} command.
Unfortunately this does not work, any clue?

For completeness I drop my code here, this is main.tex:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\input{subfile1.tex}

Look at figure \ref{fig:my_figure}

\end{document}
```

while this is subfile.tex:

```
\begin{figure}
\includegraphics[width=4cm]{logo.png}
\label{fig:my_figure}
\end{figure}

Look at figure \ref{fig:my_figure}
```

Put any image in place of my logo.png and try yourself. In my case, when I run main.tex (in TeXmaker) it shows me neither of the two references.

Comment: Please also note that `subfigure` and `subfile` means something completely different in the latex world, so be careful not to mixed them up

Comment: thanks! didn't know that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem her is that the `figure` env it self does not provide anything the label can refer to. It is the `\caption` command that provides a figure number that the `\label` can refer to.

Here is an example:

```
\begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{sub-\jobname.tex}
\begin{figure}
  \rule{4cm}{4cm}
  \caption{test}
\label{fig:my_figure}
\end{figure}

Look at figure \ref{fig:my_figure}

\end{filecontents}

\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

 \input{sub-\jobname.tex}

Look at figure \ref{fig:my_figure}

\end{document}
```